# Invalid operation: WITH RECURSIVE is not supported

Tags: amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, recursive-query

When I'm running query below I get message:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: WITH RECURSIVE is not supported;
```

Can someone explain me why recursive function doesn't work? (I'm working on amazon redshift)

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT 
        1 AS i, 
        1 AS factorial
    UNION 
    SELECT 
        i+1 AS i, 
        factorial * (i+1) as factorial 
    FROM r
    WHERE i < 10
)
SELECT * FROM r;
```

Answer (score 3):

The official Amazon Redshift documentation: [Unsupported PostgreSQL Features](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html):

> **These PostgreSQL features are not supported in Amazon Redshift.** 
>   ...
>  ...
>   - Recursive common table expressions 
>   ...

Comment: Amazon Redshift is _like_ PostgreSQL, but it is **not PostgreSQL**. Don't expect everything that works on PostgreSQL to work on Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

`WITH RECURSIVE` is now supported in Redshift starting from April 29th, 2021:

- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-redshift-announces-support-for-heirarchical-data-queries-with-recursive-cte/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html#r_WITH_clause-recursive-cte