# Moving Recursive queries from Oracle Sql to Redshift

Tags: sql, recursion, with-statement, connect-by, hierarchical-query

I am trying to move this recursive query from Oracle Sql to Redshift. In order to so, I should be able to get rid of the commands "CONNECT BY", "LEVEL" and " PRIOR" within the code written below. I was wondering to move the recursive pattern within a WITH - UNION ALL statement, but I am not sure how to manage the "LEVEL" function. Would be anyone so kind to help me to rewrite this code getting rid of "CONNECT BY", "LEVEL" and " PRIOR", but keeping the hierarchy? Thank you very much in advance.

```
WITH 
LEVEL_COUNTING AS (
SELECT 
    t.*
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS SINGLE_ELEMENT
    ,LEVEL AS element_no
FROM 
    t CONNECT BY INSTR(STR, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
    AND id = PRIOR id
    AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid operation: WITH RECURSIVE is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287067/invalid-operation-with-recursive-is-not-supported)